# Writing performant queries with EF usually bleeds business logic into data layer

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, unit-testing, entity-framework-5

With my experience with Entity Framework I find that the more and more a queries needs to be optimized the more business logic bleeds into the data layer or even lower into the database via a stored procedure. This makes unit testing more difficult and I was just wondering how people deal with this?

E.g.
I may have a function in my business layer/repository that has a bunch of business rules and logic that I have unit tests for. However I find that I can combined this into a stored procedure and return multiple result sets etc. but now my unit tests are useless.

Here is an example of placing a buy order in a stock market scenario. There are many hits to the database that bring back data, and then need to go back to the database to check to see if certain criteria is met.

I could put this into a stored procedure, but then all that logic is then pushed into the database and is harder to unit test.

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> PlaceBuyOrder(int sellOrderId, int requestedShares, int buyerUserId)
{
    if (sellOrderId <= 0) throw new ArgumentNullException("sellOrderId");
    if (requestedShares <= 0) throw new ArgumentNullException("requestedShares");
    if (buyerUserId <= 0) throw new ArgumentNullException("buyerUserId");

    // Get the sell order to check to see if the sell order still exists.
    var sellerOrderActivity = GetLatestUnprocessedOrderActivityForOrder(sellOrderId);
    if (sellerOrderActivity == null)
        yield return new ValidationResult(GlobalResources.OrderDoestExist);
    else
    {
        // Make sure when the order type is "sell all" that the 
        if (sellerOrderActivity.Order.Type == OrderTypes.SellAll && requestedShares < sellerOrderActivity.QtyRemaining)
            yield return new ValidationResult("requestedShares", GlobalResources.RequestedSharesCannotBeLessthanWhatIsBeingSold);
        else
        {
            if (requestedShares > sellerOrderActivity.QtyRemaining)
                requestedShares = sellerOrderActivity.QtyRemaining;

            var requestedSharesAmount = requestedShares * sellerOrderActivity.Price;
            if (!_financeService.CanUserAffordSharesPurchase(buyerUserId, requestedSharesAmount))
                yield return new ValidationResult(GlobalResources.InsufficentFundsToPurchaseRequestedShares);
            else if (!_financeService.CanUserAffordSharesPurchase(sellerOrderActivity.Order.UserId, 0))
                yield return new ValidationResult(GlobalResources.SellerHasInsufficentFundsAfterCommission);
            else
            {
                using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, 
                    new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted, Timeout = TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout }))
                {
                    // Insert both the order and order activity.
                    var newBuyOrderActivity = new OrderActivity
                    {
                        Price = sellerOrderActivity.Price,
                        QtyRemaining = requestedShares,
                        Status = OrderActivityStatuses.Open,
                        Order = new Order
                        {
                            Type = OrderTypes.Buy,
                            UserId = buyerUserId,
                            VideoId = sellerOrderActivity.Order.VideoId
                        }
                    };

                    _orderRepository.AddOrderActivity(newBuyOrderActivity);
                    _orderRepository.SaveChanges();

                    var sellerProcessedOrderActivity = new ProcessedOrderActivity();
                    var buyerProcessedOrderActivity = new ProcessedOrderActivity();
                    ProcessBuyAndSellOrderActivities(newBuyOrderActivity.Id, sellerOrderActivity, requestedShares, sellerProcessedOrderActivity, buyerProcessedOrderActivity);

                    if (sellerOrderActivity.Order.Type == OrderTypes.Sell && requestedShares != sellerOrderActivity.QtyRemaining)
                    {
                        var newSellerPartialOrderActivity = new OrderActivity
                        {
                            OrderId = sellerOrderActivity.OrderId,
                            Price = sellerOrderActivity.Price,
                            QtyRemaining = sellerOrderActivity.QtyRemaining - requestedShares,
                            Status = OrderActivityStatuses.Partial
                        };

                        _orderRepository.AddOrderActivity(newSellerPartialOrderActivity);
                        _orderRepository.SaveChanges();
                    }

                    var sellerAccountId = _accountRepository.GetAccountIdForUser(sellerOrderActivity.Order.UserId);
                    var sellerAccountTransaction = new Data.Model.Transaction();
                    var buyerAccountTransaction = new Data.Model.Transaction();
                    _financeService.TransferFundsFromBuyerToSeller(buyerUserId, 0, sellerOrderActivity.Order.UserId, sellerAccountId, requestedSharesAmount, 
                        sellerAccountTransaction, buyerAccountTransaction);

                    // Add the apporpriate transactions to the portfolio activity table and make 
                    // sure the seller comes before the buyer to negate the portfolio first.
                    var sellerPortfolio = new UserPortfolioActivity
                    {
                        Price = sellerOrderActivity.Price,
                        ProcessedOrderActivityId = sellerProcessedOrderActivity.Id,
                        Qty = -requestedShares,
                        TransactionId = sellerAccountTransaction.Id,
                        UserId = sellerOrderActivity.Order.UserId,
                        VideoId = sellerOrderActivity.Order.VideoId
                    };

                    var buyerPortfolio = new UserPortfolioActivity
                    {
                        Price = sellerOrderActivity.Price,
                        ProcessedOrderActivityId = buyerProcessedOrderActivity.Id,
                        Qty = requestedShares,
                        TransactionId = buyerAccountTransaction.Id,
                        UserId = buyerUserId,
                        VideoId = sellerOrderActivity.Order.VideoId
                    };

                    _userRepository.AddUserPortfolio(sellerPortfolio);
                    _userRepository.AddUserPortfolio(buyerPortfolio);
                    _userRepository.SaveChanges();

                    transactionScope.Complete();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the relevant code. Your question has multiple answers, depending on your specific problem. So it's impossible to give an answer without code.

Comment: @NicolásStraubValdivieso - hopefully that explains my problem.

Comment: and what bit is underperforming? something you can do is preload a table into memory. Obviously this could be really expensive and disastrous if the table ever grows to the millions of rows, but if you find yourself constantly getting data from a specific table, you can get a lot of speed improvements if you decorate the table's repository with a constructor that caches the table into memory. Also, I'm not entirely sure whether you can have a transactionscope work for a context that's already instantiated. In the past I've had to expose the connection to manually set the scope's transaction.

Comment: where are your repoes being instantiated? are you using the same context or two separate contexts? also where are the database reads? how are you accessing the db? Are you using a DbContext or an ObjectContext. Also, specifically, what code is the one you would need to pass to an sp and how would it look like?

Comment: @NicolásStraubValdivieso - I'm using Ninject to instantiate the contexts and I'm using DbContext. And I was thinking of putting all of that code into an sp.

Comment: can you profile the code? I can't determine what could be working slowly just by looking at it.